# Can't use ints and sum with JOption dialog boxes

Tags: java, string, swing, joptionpane

I'm using the book [Java: how to program, 7th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132222205). The problem is that after chapter 2 it no longer gives you answers. I made an application from the book that took 2 ints from the user, and then added them together and outputted the sum with a printf display message (console app).

Now the book asks me to edit that program and use the `JOption` import functions (i.e. ask for the 2 integers via `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the first integer?");` thingy. I have to make a dialog box pop up asking for the 2 integers, and then show the sum in a `messagebox` at the end.

This is what I did so far, spent an hour trying to fix the errors to no avail (no clues in the book):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Additions
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      String name1 = // return type string, pane asking for name
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the first integer?" );

      String name2 = // return type string, pane asking for name
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the second integer?" );

      sum = name + name2;

      String sum = String.format( "Sum is %d\n", sum );
   } 
}
```

Comment: so where is the messagebox at the end? Also, the "+" does string concatentation on strings. You need to convert the values to int [(see Integer.parseInt())](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 5):

You have to convert that String into an int. You can do it with this method.

```
String s =JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the first integer?" );
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Take care that if the input is not an int then a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Read api :[Integer#parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

So in your code would be something like this:

```
 String name1 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the first integer?" );
 int first = Integer.parseInt(name1);
 String name2 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the second integer?" );
 int second = Integer.parseInt(name2);
 String sum = String.format( "Sum is %d\n", first + second );
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sum); // show output
```

Comment: Thanks for that. in reality i'd like to get rid of the "name1,2" name's and add number1 and number2, is that ok?

Comment: @user2850549 I don't understand what you mean. `name1` is a variable that you want to hold an int, so it's ok to rename it with `number1` it's more clear.

Comment: cool, yeah i've renamed those, this is what i have so far. but it's still outputting 3 errors. import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Additions
{
   
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      
 
   
      
   String number1 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the first integer?" );
      int i = Integer.parseInt( number1 );
   

      String number2 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the first integer?" );
   int i = Integer.parseInt( number2 );
   
   
   sum = number1 + number2;

      
   String sum = 
     String.format( "Sum is %d\n", sum );

Comment: im so confused, is it possible you could edit the code so it will output for me? as im stuck onthis over and hour and a half now ! cheers

Comment: use another type of JOptionPane, more in Oracle tutorial how to use Dialogs, JOptionPane.showInputDialog is designated to take String, but is possible to returns an Object (date, number, etc) from JComboBox,